# Adjust a colored box to the text

Tags: tcolorbox

Hi I got a problem with my colored box, it's not adjusting to my text, how can I fix that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please copy code from your editor. With a screenshot we have to retype it. Thank you

Comment: In addition to following up on @MS-SPO's request, please indicate which document class you employ, and please clarify what you mean by "it's not adjusting to my text".

Comment: the option square creates a square box.

Comment: How or where are the colors `beige` and `rose_saumon` defined?

Answer (score 4):

Just drop the option `square`and use the option `hbox` for adjusting the width of the box to the text, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Regular box]
        this is just some text
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=A box with hbox, hbox ]
        this is just some text
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Note that `hbox` makes sense only in those cases where the width of your text is smaller than `\textwidth`. If you have longer text then the width of the `tcolorbox` could be fixed manually (e.g., by putting the `tcolorbox` inside a `minipage` environment).

Comment: You should emphasize, that that `hbox` works and has sense if the text has only one line, which is  shorter than  `\textwidth`.

Comment: @Zarko: true -- thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hey @avirsty, did this solve your problem?